# Brute force loops?

Tags: loops, knapsack-problem

A farmer wants to buy 100 animals. He has 100 dollars. The prices are as follows: Pigs = 10 dollars. Hens = 3 dollars. Pigeons = 0.5 dollars. He must buy at least one of each animal. My task is to show whether there are multiple solutions to this problem and to stop the program when there is found one.

I'm guessing it has something to do with using a "brute force" method. I've tried declaring the variables and using a while loop with an if statement for each animal, but that didn't work.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.  You would be better off to keep trying different approaches than to simply ask others for the answer.  Don't give up.

Comment: It's not homework. I should mention i am only 2 weeks into my programming course and i have already tried several methods to approach this problem, but those are gone now.

Comment: I am having trouble how to approach it. I have been told to use some nested loops (maybe for each animal), but i don't see how that would work and how to print all the solutions (if any).